# labels color change in a loop. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, colors, label

I have 180 labels and checking a condition in a for loop which runs 180 times. How can I change the labels color in the loop for every particular label?

My code:

```
for (Int16 i = 1; i < 181; i++)
{    
    try
    {
        // Do some thing    
    }    

    catch (Exception ex)
    {    
        // this works for only one label i want to make it   
        // dynamic like below..and i want to make color change if it catch      
        // any Exception for the respective loop.               
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;           

        // this doesn't works
        label[i].ForeColor = Color.Blue;       
    }

    finally
    {
         //Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you receive an error?

Comment: If you are using web then there is a way to get element by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you should write a function like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
UpdateLabelFG(this.Controls, Color.Red);
}


private void UpdateLabelFG(ControlCollection controls, Color fgColor)
{
if (controls == null)
    return;
foreach (Control C in controls) {
    if (C is Label)
        ((Label)C).ForeColor = fgColor;
    if (C.HasChildren)
        UpdateLabelFG(C.Controls, fgColor);
}
}
```

Comment: if the loop is running and for example it catches the exception and i want to know at which no. of iteration exception occurs and to see the exception respective label should change its color.

Comment: you need to put it inside try catch then :)

Comment: it will change all the labels color or certain labels which have the exception regarding no. of iteration.

Comment: If you want it can change all the labels, but if you don't want you can but certain conditions and it will behave accordingly, That's why I suggested a function instead of writing the code inside the form or button

Comment: i put it in catch and still unable to use this function. getting errors in build. can u help me to use this function.

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection' D:\C#\MoveAndStatus\readTxt\readTxt\Paramerters.cs 61 27 readTxt

Comment: Error 4 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection' D:\C#\MoveAndStatus\readTxt\readTxt\Paramerters.cs 112 35 readTxt

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'readTxt.Paramerters.UpdateLabelFG(System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection, System.Drawing.Color)' has some invalid arguments D:\C#\MoveAndStatus\readTxt\readTxt\Paramerters.cs 61 13 readTxt

Comment: Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'readTxt.Paramerters.UpdateLabelFG(System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection, System.Drawing.Color)' has some invalid arguments D:\C#\MoveAndStatus\readTxt\readTxt\Paramerters.cs 112 21 readTxt

Comment: this is because the types of parameter to method are different

Comment: i would suggest you to got to chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56767/discussion-between-wafeeq-and-arijit-mukherjee).

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is accessing a single control by it's name
if you want to retrieve all labels in your form and change Forecolor  you have to try  the following

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();
    foreach (var label in labels)
    {
        label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put in your try 
label[i].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(i + 1 ), rnd.Next(i + 1), rnd.Next(i + 1));